Replace Tokens - 'init' not found - name not supplied
I need to replace a particular file tokens, so I have set the sources to
src/some_folder/somes_cript.py

As the pipeline is launched, the template is called and ran properly
but I get these errors:
token pattern '__\s*((?:(?!__)(?!\s*__).)*)\s*__'
transform pattern '\s*(.*)\(\s*((?:(?!\()(?!\s*\)).)*)\s*\)\s*'
 replacing tokens in '/home/someuser/agent/_work/8/s/src/some_folder/somes_cript.py'
encoding 'ascii'
##[error]variable 'init' not found
init: 
##[error]Error: name not supplied

This is my pipeline template :
parameters:
  - name: targetDirectory
    type: string
    default: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'

steps:
  - task: qetza.replacetokens.replacetokens-task.replacetokens@6
    name: replace_tokens
    displayName: "Inject secrets"
    inputs:
      root: "${{ parameters.targetDirectory }}"
      sources: |
        **/src/some_folder/somes_cript.py
      tokenPattern: 'doubleunderscores'
      logLevel: 'debug'
      missingVarLog: 'error'


Can you share more details about the File Structure in the repo? In what path is the py file located? On the other hand, are you using multiple repo resources in YAML Pipeline?

I made it work just using **/src/some_folder_some_script.py but I get an error : ##[error]variable 'init' not found

just edited my question

Have you define the Pipeline variable init in your yaml piepline? And how you define the init in your py file? If possible, can you share some details?

init is nowhere to be found, apart from the _ init _ python constructors of course

The replace token task will use the Pipeline variable to replace the init tag in the py file. So can you clarify how you define it? And What is your purpose of using this task? Init is not the expected replacement value, right?

I just realized my stupidity, I'll have to use something else than doubleunderscores

Yes. You can change to use doublebraces ({{...}}) in replace token task. The default value is #{...}# . If you don't define tokenPattern.

When you use Replace token task and the doubleunderscores type token patten, it will replace all values with the format: __var__ in the target file.
When we use __init__ python constructor, it will be identified as a variable that needs to be changed. In this case, it will try to find the variable: init in Pipeline.
To solve this issue, we can change to use other type of token patterns in the Replace token task. (default value: #{...}#)
parameters:
  - name: targetDirectory
    type: string
    default: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'

steps:
  - task: qetza.replacetokens.replacetokens-task.replacetokens@6
    name: replace_tokens
    displayName: "Inject secrets"
    inputs:
      root: "${{ parameters.targetDirectory }}"
      sources: |
        **/src/some_folder/somes_cript.py
      logLevel: 'debug'
      missingVarLog: 'error'

In py file, you can use the format: #{varname}# to set the variable that need to be replaced.
For example:
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = #{name}#
        self.age = age

    def display_info(self):
        print(f"Name: {self.name}")
        print(f"Age: {self.age}")

Other supportted values:

tokenPattern: azpipelines  $(...)


tokenPattern: doublebraces {{...}}


tokenPattern: githubactions ${{ ... }}


tokenPattern: octopus #{ ... }


tokenPattern: custom

